# File/Directory Path should look like this - Powershell output

Tags: windows, powershell, output, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I am using a Powershell Script which should create a file that includes the Directory-Order (folder, subfolder, files, etc.):

```
$path = "golf.de/dgv" 
Get-ChildItem -Path $folder -recurse | sort Directory, Name| format-Table -auto $path, Directory, Name | Out-File C:\Users\J.Kammermeier\Desktop\Johannes\testtext.txt
```

until now the output looks like this

```
C:\Users\J.Kammermeier\Desktop\Johannes                        Test-Datei1.txt         
C:\Users\J.Kammermeier\Desktop\Johannes                        Test-Datei2.txt
C:\Users\J.Kammermeier\Desktop\Johannes\Sonstige Datein\Musik  WACKEN.txt
```

but I need it in this order:

```
.../Johannes                         Test-Datei1.txt 

...Johannes\Sonstige Datein\Musik    WACKEN.txt
```

How to achieve it?

Comment: Please provide us the script, I will make it work for you :)

Comment: $path = "golf.de/dgv"
Get-ChildItem -Path $folder -recurse | sort Directory, Name| format-Table -auto $path, Directory, Name | Out-File C:\Users\J.Kammermeier\Desktop\Johannes\testtext.txt

Comment: So... you just want the "C:\Users\J.Kammermeier\Desktop\" part removed, that's it?

Comment: yes    only the "Johannes" and the folder after "Johannes" should be left

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll have to mangle the `Directory` property a bit, using `Select-Object` and [calculated properties](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx):

```
# Set the path and folder property
$path = "golf.de/dgv"
$folder = "C:\Users\J.Kammermeier\Desktop\Johannes"

# Get the name of the parent folder (the part we want to remove)
$basePath = (Get-Item $folder).Parent.FullName

# Retrieve the files
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $folder -Recurse 

# Select the Name property and then two calculated properties, "Directory" and "Path"
$files = $files |Select-Object @{Name="BaseURL";Expression={"$path"}},
                               @{Name="Directory";Expression={$_.Directory.FullName.Substring($basePath.Length - 1)}},
                               Name

# Sort them
$files = $files |Sort-Object Directory, Name
# Formatted output to file
$files | Format-Table -AutoSize | Out-File C:\Users\J.Kammermeier\Desktop\Johannes\testtext.txt
```

From the details, I guess that you're trying to audit the files for a website, you could combine the `Path` and `Directory` properties and fix the back slashes with `-replace`:

```
@{Name="URLPath";Expression={"$path/" + $($_.Directory.FullName.Substring($basePath.Length - 1) -replace "\\","/")}}
```